# Eigenvectors of the product of a symmetric matrix and a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is a symmetric matrix with one negative eigenvalue while the rest are strictly positive. Let $B$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix. I know there is a result in linear algebra that guarantees that the eigenvalues of $AB$ have the same signs as those of $A$. Can something be said about the relation between the eigenvectors of $A$ and $AB$? For example, is there a bound on the angle between the eigenvector of $A$ and $AB$ corresponding to their unique negative eiganvlue?